# Backbone.js inaccessible object attributes

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, backbone.js

I'm having a problem that I really can't comprehend… I'm not sure if backbone is doing some voodoo to these objects but I can't seem to get even raw access to them.

My basic problem is, sometimes when I load the page, fetch the models and render the views one collection will only show/render 50% of the time. I assumed this was an issue with the model not being populated but after some investigation, I could see the model was populated but not accessable.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have attached a few screenshots of working and not working to illustrate my point(sanity).

**Page loading fine - model accessed**
[image: Page loading fine - model accessed]

**Page not loading correctly - model inaccessible**
[image: Page not loading correctly - model inaccessible]

**The object when *is* loading correctly**
[image: The object when is loading correctly]

**The object when *not* loading correctly**
[image: The object when not loading correctly]

Comment: Sounds like an ajax thing. Are you trying to use it before it has loaded? (But sometimes you get lucky and it has loaded by then)

Comment: it feels that way too but in console I can spew out the object before I try and access it. If you look at the image titled "Page not loading correctly - model inaccessible", that object shown will show the same as the image above but I can't get hold of the data.

Comment: console.dir is a lot more complex then that. it shows you a live object, not the real object. If you try to log `$.extend(true, {}, obj)` (or some other clone) then you can log the real object.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you out unless they see the code that you use to load the model (e.g. the function that fetches) and the code that does the parsing for the model.  Also, I'm not sure its wise to store collections as attributes in models.  I usually leave attributes as simple, non-complex properties.

Comment: @Raynos Fantastic thanks, I didn't know I could log the real object — really useful. Looks like thats the issue then… appreciate the help! If you'd like to move your answer into the main answer section then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debugging attempts are going wrong.

console.dir is a lot more complex then that. it shows you a live object, not the real object.

If you try to log `$.extend(true, {}, obj)` (or some other clone) then you can log the real object.

As mentioned it sounds like an ajax thing. Are you trying to use it before it has loaded? (But sometimes you get lucky and it has loaded by then).

We need more information. A jsfiddle would be the best.

Comment: spot on — using $.extend(true, {}, obj) showed that the model had not been loaded in yet (it was an issue with fetching data for nested collections). Thanks again.