# backbone.js model attributes not available at runtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I am at the end of my mental leash with this one...

I am attempting to render a view to the screen that contains a model object attribute.  I am able to get the html to render but the model attribute is not inserted into the div as expected but is instead rendering as **undefined**.

The thing that makes this so frustrating is that when I log the view object to the console I am able to inspect it and see that the correct model is associated with it and that the user's attributes are indeed present via **this > model > attributes**.  However, if try to access the attributes directly in my code and then log that to the console I get **undefined**.

**router show action**

```
show: function(customer_id){
      var customer = new backbone_data.Models.Customer({id: customer_id});
      customer.fetch();
      var customerView = new backbone_data.Views.CustomerView({model: customer});   
      $("#app_container").append(customerView.render().el);
}
```

**render function in view class -- both of these do not work**

```
render: function(){
        this.$el.html("<h3>Hello, my age is "+this.model.get('age')+"</h3>");
        return this;
}

template: _.template("<h3>Hello, my age is <%= age %></h3>"),
render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
}
```

**console image showing object attributes**
I am logging these from inside the view's render function like so:

```
render: function(){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.model.attributes.age);
        this.$el.html("<h3>Hello, my age is "+this.model.get('age')+"</h3>");
        return this;
}
```

You can see from the screenshot that while the age attribute is accessible when logging the view object in the console, it is **undefined** when logging it directly in my code and rendering as **undefined** in the view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK5xB.jpg

Thanks for the help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`customer.fetch()` performs an asynchronous request to populate the model's data. Your code creates the view and passes it the model immediately after you `fetch()`. Try this:

```
customer.fetch({
    success: function(data)
    {
        var customerView = new backbone_data.Views.CustomerView({model: data});   
        $("#app_container").append(customerView.render().el);
    }
});
```

That should wait until the `fetch()` is completed and ensure that the data you want has been retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was exactly what the issue was.  One thing that was tripping me up was that the console was displaying the object  when the object had not actually been returned yet.  How should I think about the timing of the console and how it displays data?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another similar question where inspecting the object in the console led to thinking that the object had been returned from the AJAX request when it actually had not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282451/backbone-js-inaccessible-object-attributes?rq=1

Comment: @louism2 - Glad I could help. My approach is to use JSON.stringfy() when printing an object to the console but even that isn't perfect. I suppose more than anything just keep in mind that the console is referencing the object in it's current state and not necessarily it's state when console.log() was called.